# SQL Daily restore

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, restore

Been trying and failing to write a script that restores a SQL database backup file daily.

The file backup is in the following format Backup_28_04_2020. I need the script to take the latest file and restore it to a database called [CallDatabase]. Its the date that's throwing me off, because it changes every day.

Any help appreciated.

DB is SQL server 2016.

The script I am trying below. The script is parsing but failing with error below.

> "Error converting data type varchar to nvarchar. [SQLSTATE 42000]
>   (Error 8114).  The step failed."

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(255), @PathToBackup varchar(255), @RestoreFilePath varchar(1000)
DECLARE @Files TABLE (subdirectory varchar(255), depth int, [file] int)
 SET NOCOUNT ON

 SET @PathToBackup = 'H:\'

 -- insert into our memory table using dir tree and a single file level
 INSERT INTO @Files
 EXEC master.dbo.xp_DirTree @PathToBackup,1,1

 SELECT TOP 1 
    @FileName = [subdirectory]
 FROM 
    @Files
 WHERE
    -- get where it is a file
    [file] = 1
 AND    
    subdirectory LIKE 'Backup_%.bak'
 ORDER BY
    -- order descending so newest file will be first by naming convention
    subdirectory DESC

IF LEFT(REVERSE(@PathToBackup), 1) != '\'
BEGIN
    SET @PathToBackup = @PathToBackup + '\'
END

SET @RestoreFilePath = @PathToBackup + @FileName

SELECT @RestoreFilePath

RESTORE DATABASE [CallDatabase] 
FROM DISK = @RestoreFilePath
WITH FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to add the script into the question. Also, please add the tag for the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Script is parsing but failing to run job with error,

Comment: Have you seen the dbatools powershell module? Among other things, there are cmdlets for working with backups and restoring them. For your use case, I'd look at `Get-DbaBackupInformation` and `Restore-DbaDatabase`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide more details while restoring the DB. Also, delcare `@RestoreFilePath` as `nvarchar (1000)`:

```
DECLARE @DBNAME SYSNAME = 'CallDatabase'    --'DBName'
DECLARE @DATA NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'H:\' + @DBNAME + '.mdf'    --'Path of data file'
DECLARE @LOG NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'H:\' + @DBNAME + '.ldf'     --'Path of log file'

RESTORE DATABASE [CallDatabase] 
FROM DISK = @RestoreFilePath
WITH FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'CallDatabase_Data' TO @DATA,  
MOVE N'CallDatabase_Log' TO @LOG, 
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
```

HTH.

Comment: I dont have a log file though, this is error I get after changing @RestoreFilePath to Nvarchar,       SQLAgent. Invalid zero-length device name. Reissue the BACKUP statement with a valid device name. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3044)  RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013).  The step failed.

Comment: @Blehhhh try to print each variable used in the final restore command and see if every value is correct.